# Heroku Config Vars and Django

Tags: django, heroku

I want to make specific settings for each environment (local vs staging). I set up Config Vars in my heroku staging app and set DEBUG setting to false to try it out, but it didn't work. Am I missing something or making it wrong?

My seetings.py file
[image: My seetings.py file]

Config Vars in the staging app
[image: Config Vars in the staging app]

Result when I tried somthing wrong
[image: Result when I tried somthing wrong]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a directory where your current `settings.py` file is located and name it `settings`. Then create a `base.py`, `dev.py`, and `prod.py` file in this directory.

Also create an `__init__.py` in the same location as these 3 settings files and inside that `__init__.py` put `from your_project_name.settings.base import *`. In `base.py` you'll have all the shared settings between prod and dev, and in `prod.py` and `dev.py` you would just `from .base import *` to 'inherit' the settings from the base.py file. This is one of the only cases where it's recommended to import like this.

Then you can set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in production to use `my_project_name.settings.prod` instead of the default settings variable.

Answer (score 0):

`DEBUG` in the settings file needs to be set via the environment variable, if available.

So change `DEBUG = True` to `DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', True)` and you should be fine.  This is usually called a feature flag (pattern).

---

Responding:

If you are using a "two scoops" pattern, @wjh18 is on the right path.

The pattern I outlined is solid, in use for years.

Can you see what the python terminal grabs on Heroku via `heroku run bash --app APPNAME`, then `python` then `import os` then `os.environ.get('DEBUG')`.  The should match your settings on Heroku.  If so, there may be something in the stack that is inhibiting settings (lazy load) from working correct.

A number of gotcha exist in Django is you deviate from established patterns.

Just in case, the env var is ONLY for the Django settings page, otherwise access the Django `DEBUG` via proper import of settings (`from django.conf import settings`).

Comment: Still the same problem. What I want is to make DEBUG = True in my local settings.py file, and DEBUG = False on my staging or production settings.py file deployed in heroku.